# Substitution cipher decryption using letter frequency analysis for text without blanks and special characters

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cryptography, statistics, artificial-intelligence

I need to find the plain text for given cipher text. I also have statistics (in an Excel document) for the letters in the given language e.g. I have the frequencies of the letters and also of the digraphs.

I tried this approach so far: I evaluated the frequency of each letter in the cipher text I received. Then I sorted the letters in descending order by their frequencies and mapped each letter with the corresponding letter from the Excel document. The problem with this approach is that it gives me some text that has no meaning at all. That is because my text is pretty small (only 1500 characters long).

I considered doing some limited permutations, but I have no idea what could I use to evaluate how good some permutation is. I think a good evaluation function would solve my problem.

Be aware that all special characters and white spaces are removed from the text. Also there are no numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for fully automated decryption

- you need to add some dictionary of commonly used words
- and compare against it
- the solution that finds most words from it is probably the right one

with letter probabilities comes few problems

- they are derived for common texts
- so if your encrypted text is for example technical paper and not beletry ...
- or it includes equations or tables
- then it can screw your overall letter occurence

so do it like this:

1. compute the probabilities of letters
2. divide letters into groups by probabilities

   - so commonly used (high probability) letters are grouped together (group A)
   - so less common used (mid probability) letters are grouped together (group B)
   - and the rest (low probability) also group together (group C)
3. substitute group A

   - first see if group A probabilities match your language
   - if not then the text is in different language,style/form,or it is not a plain text at all
   - in such case you can not proceed safely
   - if they match then substitute letters from group A
   - they should be OK on the first run
4. try substitute group B

   - so you know all the letters from group B (encrypted/decrypted)
   - so generate all permutations of substitutions
   - for each one try to decipher text
   - and search for words after decryption (ignoring not yet substituted letters)
   - compute the word count percentage
   - and remember the best one (or few top ones)
5. try substitute group C

   - do it the same as bullet 4
6. corrections

   - it is probable that in the final result will be few letters mixed
   - so there are ways to handle also this
   - you can have table of letters that are mixable between each other
   - so you can try permutate them and test against your dictionary
   - or find words in your text with 1-2 wrong letters per word (for bigger words like 5 or more letters)
   - and permutate/correct substitution of the wrong letters if enough such words found

[notes]

- you can obtain dictionaries from translators
- also saw some plain text translator tables online
- the groups should have distinct probability difference to each other
- number of groups can change with language
- I had best results for this task with semi automated approach
- steps 5,6 can use user input